# Module Load Optimisation for Client Side Rendering of components in Nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

In Nextjs app, when multiple components of a page are using the same package then you might expect the common package to be loaded only once by default, but it is not the case when the components are client side rendered, increasing the page size by great extent. Below is a use case which shows the same.

I have 4 components "Chart1", "Chart2", "Chart3", "Chart4" with the exact same code of a plot using 'react-plotly.js' package. When these components are loaded with ssr set to false, the 'react-plotly.js' package in each components are loaded for each module. The network data shows 5.4MB loaded 4 times - once for each of the component. But when i load 'react-plotly.js' in _app.js and pass it as Context, then there is only 1 occurrence of 5.4MB load corresponding to the first load.
Wanted to check if Nextjs does any optimisation at all to avoid redundant package loads across the entirety of app when ssr is false ? Is there a way to force this optimisation ?

Below is the page code

```
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";

const Chart1 = dynamic(() => import('@/components/scheduling/Chart1'), {
  ssr: false,
});

const Chart2 = dynamic(() => import('@/components/scheduling/Chart2'), {
  ssr: false,
});

const Chart3 = dynamic(() => import('@/components/scheduling/Chart3'), {
  ssr: false,
});

const Chart4 = dynamic(() => import('@/components/scheduling/Chart4'), {
  ssr: false,
});

export default function scheduling() {

  return(
    <div>
      <Chart1 />
      <Chart2 />
      <Chart3 />
      <Chart4 />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Below are the component code

```
import Plot from "react-plotly.js"

import { PlotlyContext } from "@/pages/_app"
import { useContext } from "react"


export default function Chart1() {

  // const Plot = useContext(PlotlyContext)

  return(
    <Plot
      data={[
        {
          x: [7, 2, 3],
          y: [2, 6, 3],
          type: 'scatter',
          mode: 'lines+markers',
          marker: {color: 'red'},
        },
        {type: 'bar', x: [1, 2, 3], y: [2, 5, 3]},
      ]}
      layout={ {width: 320, height: 240, title: 'Chart 1'} }
    />
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the case when running in dev mode only, and not after build production mode.